# NLog Doesn't Write Log Entries Into Database

Tags: .net, nlog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <!-- add your targets here -->

    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="f"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} | ${logger} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${message}${newline}    ${callsite} | ${stacktrace}" />

    <!-- This will set the normal console. I find the colored much nicer :) -->
    <!--
   <target  xsi:type="Console"
            name="console" 
            layout="${shortdate} ${message}" /> -->

    <target  xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
            name="console"
            layout="${shortdate} ${message}" />

    <!-- my not-working database target -->
    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="database"
            connectionStringName="CRMTool"
            dbProvider="sqlclient"
            installConnectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CRMTool;Integrated Security=true;"
            commandText="insert into LogEntries(Date,Level,Logger,Message,MachineName, UserName, Callsite, ThreadId, Exception, InnerException, Stacktrace, ErrorSource, ErrorClass, ErrorMethod, ErrorMessage, InnerErrorMessage) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message,@machinename, @user_name, @call_site, @threadid, @log_exception, @log_innerexception, @stacktrace, @ErrorSource, @ErrorClass, @ErrorMethod, @ErrorMessage, @InnerErrorMessage);">

      <install-command text="CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEntries](
                  [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                  [Level] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
                  [Message] [varchar](4095) NOT NULL,
                  [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
                  [Logger] [varchar](200) NULL,
                  [MachineName] [varchar](100) NULL,
                  [UserName] [varchar](100) NULL,
                  [CallSite] [varchar](100) NULL,
                  [ThreadId] [varchar](100) NULL,
                  [Exception] [varchar](max) NULL,
                  [InnerException] [varchar](max) NULL,
                  [Stacktrace] [varchar](max) NULL,
                  ErrorSource [varchar](max) NULL,
                  ErrorClass [varchar](max) NULL,
                  ErrorMethod [varchar](max) NULL,
                  ErrorMessage [varchar](max) NULL,
                  InnerErrorMessage [varchar](max) NULL,
                  CONSTRAINT [PK_LogEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
                  ([Id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
                  ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CRMTool;Integrated Security=true;" ignoreFailures="false" />


      <uninstall-command text="DROP TABLE [dbo].[LogEntries]"
          connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CRMTool;Integrated Security=true;" ignoreFailures="false" />

      <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}"/>
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
      <parameter name="@machinename" layout="${machinename}"/>
      <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
      <parameter name="@threadid" layout="${threadid}"/>
      <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${event-context:item=error-source}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorClass" layout="${event-context:item=error-class}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMethod" layout="${event-context:item=error-method}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=error-message}" />
      <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=inner-error-message}" />
      <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}"/>
      <parameter name="@log_innerexception" layout="${exception:method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}"/>
      <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}"/>
    </target>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Another post [Target database not working with NLog 3.1 and Windsor Castle Logging Facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592291/target-database-not-working-with-nlog-3-1-and-windsor-castle-logging-facility) provides some hints, questioning whether the LogEntries table was manually created, and stating that the install-command is not run automatically because NLOG does not run them by itself. The command line tool called InstallNLogConfig.exe which was supposed to runs the command was "strangely" removed from the nuget package.

The solution from [Error in execution while using NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000658/error-in-execution-while-using-nlog) didn't work either. I wanted to specify down within the tags section that NLog.2.1.0 is concerned, but this info required a higher level of reputation. Anyway ...

I would appreciate any idea leading to getting the program write the log entries into the SqlServer database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the insert statement: tried to insert a string date where datetime was expected, and [CallSite] size was also insufficient, so I increased it to max. Once those issues were addressed, it worked!